# problemas com o gulp

Tags: gulp, yarn

fala galera, comecei a fazer uns testes com yarn e o gulp. Estava tudo indo de boa, mas ontem eu baixei um template (este template https://github.com/Merukeru/angular1-gulp-template), fiz o passo a passo e paah meu gulp parou de funcionar e não sei o pq disso, poderiam me ajudar?

obs: no projeto de teste, parou também

segue o erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: essa linha de exclusão com `!node_modules` não está a dizer para ignorar a diretoria de onde estás a importar coisas?

Comment: este é um template pronto, baixei pra aprender, já veio assim. No meu trabalho funciona, mas na minha maquina não. e ainda parou o outro projeto que já funcionava com o gulp

Comment: Dá algum erro? Já fizeste `yarn install`?

Comment: nenhum erro no yarn install, acho que pode ser algum erro no node. Quando chegar em casa vou reinstalar pra ver

Comment: Consegui resolver. eu estava instalando o gulp global pelo yarn e isso estava dando como sucesso, mas desconfigurava o gulp. Tive que retirar tudo e refazer pelo npm que funcionou com sucesso.